# Bind a click navigation to changing text that uses an interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, bind, onclicklistener

I have a simple text scroller that I am using to change up the text being displayed. It shifts between three slogans on the screen and is working fine. However, now I have a request to have a click event that allows users to go back and forth between the messages. It would be nice if when I clicked the back or forward that the interval but for now I just need to create a forward and back link and have them navigate through the messages. Any suggestions?

Here is the html:

```
<a href="#">Previous</a>                            
<span class="houseFontMedium txtAlg" id="sloganSwitcher"> TQuis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam</span>
<a href="#">Next</a>
```

Here is the basic script i am using:

```
$(function() {
var texts = [" Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam", "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum.", "Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet."];
var count = 0;
function changeText() {
    $("#sloganSwitcher").html(texts[count]);
    count < 3 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(changeText, 1000);
});
```

Here is a fiddle:

[The Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ke7c/3/)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use `var tId=setInterval...` then in next and previous use `clearInterval(tId); count++; setInterval(...)`

Comment: Sorry can you explain a tad bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 links with ID prev and next

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/NcSn9/)

```
var texts = [
    "0 TQuis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam",
    "1 Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam", 
    "2 At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum.", 
    "3 Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet."];
var count = 1,tId,maxLength=texts.length;

function nav(dir) {
  clearInterval(tId);
  count+=dir;
  if (count>=maxLength) count=0;
  if (count<0) count=maxLength-1;
  $("#sloganSwitcher").html(texts[count]);    
  init();  
}
function init() {
  tId=setInterval(function() {
    if (count>=maxLength) count=0;
      $("#sloganSwitcher").html(texts[count]);
      count++;
  }, 3000);
}
$(function() {
  $("#prev").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    nav(-1);
  });
  $("#next").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    nav(1);
  });
  init();  
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ke7c/6/  Yes I would like to basically start and stop. But it does not seem to be working. Am I missing something?

Comment: typos. I am fixing it

Comment: I see your working demo... That's basically what I need. So the text is always scrolling, but the user can go back or forward to view the text. No request for a start button which would make sense so assume they want it just to restart after the interval time. So when I go back, the interval is reset back to the standard time and then resumes playing. If that makes sense.

Comment: Please see update. If you are very quick and click prev before the text changes, you need to click twice